# How to create a printable sorted list of files in a directory and subdirectories without the path with Windows 10 PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file, sorting, directory, subdirectory

I am looking for a way to create a **printable sorted list of files in a directory and subdirectories without the path** with Windows 10 **PowerShell**.

I have tried the following in Command Prompt, but it does not allow me to obtain a sorted list:

D:\books>forfiles /m *.* /s >d:\books\bookslist.txt

Is there a way to do this in Windows PowerShell?

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-ChildItem is used to list files in powershell. You may have to start go through the basic commands in powershell. Hope this helps!

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" *.* -Recurse -File | Select-Object Name | Sort-Object Name | Out-File "C:\temp\fileslist.txt"
```

Comment: Hi.
I tried the suggestion offered, but it will not sort.
The Sort-Object with the -Recurse could be in conflict
Could you suggest a solution?

Comment: Why do you think it will be a conflict? Sort will get through the list only after Get-childitem return it's results.

Comment: Hi. Dilly B. First, thanks for your much-appreciated input, which, as a newbie, encouraged me to learn more about PowerShell to help me build a PKM. The script listed all the files from the directory and subdirectories, but not sorted. I tried tweaking the script from suggestions on the web, but nothing I could grasp. There was a suggestion that there could be a conflict with the commands, and I mentioned it in case it made sense. Any ideas?

Comment: @MarioCrespi - I have edited my answer, Added 'Name' to Sort-Object.  Could you please check now.

Comment: WOW! Dilly B. It worked. THANKS!
And thanks for being a great contributor.
You help us improve our tools, and we are only as good as the tools we make.